# Two where clauses for multiple tables throwing ORA-01722: invalid number

Tags: database, oracle, join, oracle12c

I've a query which is working with single where clause condition, but not with multiple columns. Verified by doing `TO_CHAR` also. but still throwing

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number
```

Tried by doing `TO_CHAR`. Working with only single where clause. Same error with Join.

```
SELECT msa.messageid,
       msa.deviceid,
       msa.starttime,
       msa.endtime,
       (msa.endtime - msa.starttime) l2ctime,
       fca.req_timestamp,
       fca.resp_timestamp,
       (fca.resp_timestamp - fca.req_timestamp) fttcproctime
  FROM msdaudit msa JOIN are_fttc_audit fca ON msa.id = fca.external_id
 WHERE msa.messageid IN ('12334');



SELECT msa.messageid,
       msa.deviceid,
       msa.starttime,
       msa.endtime,
       (msa.endtime - msa.starttime) l2ctime,
       fca.req_timestamp,
       fca.resp_timestamp,
       (fca.resp_timestamp - fca.req_timestamp) fttcproctime
  FROM msdaudit msa, are_fttc_audit fca
 WHERE     msa.id = fca.external_id
       AND msa.messageid IN ('12334');
```

Comment: What happens if you remove `WHERE` clause completely? Perhaps `messageid` isn't to blame, but invalid values in `endtime`, `starttime`, `resp_timestamp` and `req_timestamp`.

Comment: Look at the execution plans; you'll see that the order it filters and joins tables is changing, as the optimiser takes the additional condition into account Without the DDL, query and plan details it's hard to say how to fix it - not storing numbers as strings would be a good start, of course *8-)

Comment: My bad. I used wrong foreign key which was number. and other one was varchar. Suppose to use msa.messageID as foreignKey instead of msa.id

msa.id = fca.external_id

msa.id = NUMBER
fca.external_id = VARCHAR2

The error is generic which will say "invalid number" because its trying to convert from char to number while mapping.